# Any use case where a queue is preferable than a circular queue?

Tags: data-structures, queue

Circular queue is obviously better because it helps us to use the empty space left by popping out the elements. It also saves time that may have been used to do lateral shift of elements after each pop.

But is there any use case where queue would be preferred than using a circular queue?

Definition of Queue = We will go with the linear array implementation. Follows FIFO and no overwrites

Definition of Circular Queue = Ring Buffer Implementation. Follows FIFO. No overwrites.

Comment: Circular queue is not "obviously better" in all situations. In particular, it's a terrible choice if you need an unbounded queue, because you end up having to re-allocate when the number of items exceeds the pre-allocated size, and then you have unused space at the front of the array when the number of items is reduced. A linked list can be a much better way to implement an unbounded queue.

Comment: In this case we are using the array implementation, so both are bounded.

Answer (score 5):

*Note:* In many languages a `queue` is just an interface and doesn't say anything about the implementation.

When using an array based circular queue, a.k.a ring buffer, you must handle the situation where you push to a full buffer. You could:

1. Ignore the insertion
2. Overwrite the oldest entry
3. Block until there's space again
4. (Re)Allocate memory and copy all the content
5. Use an oversized buffer so this situation never happens

Each of these options have downsides. If you can live with them or you know that you will never fill the buffer, then ring buffer is the way to go.

Options 3 & 4 will induce stuttering. Depending on your use case, you might prefer *longer but stable access time and reliability* over *occasional spikes* and therefore opt for a `linked list` or some other sort of dynamic implementation, like a `deque`, instead.

Example use cases are tasks, where you have to achieve a stable frame/sampling rate or throughput and you can't tolerate stutters, like:

- Realtime video and audio processing
- Realtime rendering
- Networking
- Thread pools when you don't want the threads to block for too long when pushing new jobs.

**However, a queue based on a linear array will suffer from the same downsides. I don't see a reason for choosing a linear queue over a circular queue.**
(Besides the slightly higher implementation complexity.)

`std::queue` in C++ uses a `deque` as underlaying container by default. `deque` is essentially a dynamic array of arrays which seems like a good base for most use cases because it allocates memory in small chunks and hence induces less stuttering.

Comment: Sorry for not defining the data structures. I have edited the question. Can you provide a practical use case for the same?